# Does A Google Adwords api keywordid only have 1 matchtype?

Tags: google-ads-api

Trying to figure out the best way to tell the different in matchtype (`broad`,`phrase`,`exact`) returned by `KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`.

I can run a `GetAdGroupCriterion` - and that tells me match type... but it is unique to each keywordid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the "KeywordMatchType" field to your report and you will be shown the match type in use for each keyword.